# Awk Matrix multiplication

Tags: bash, awk, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to write an AWK command that allows me to perform matrix multiplication between two tab separated files.

example:

cat m1

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

cat m2

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

desired output:

```
 50  60
114 140
```

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @glennjackman Essentially I'm unsure how I would be able to fill an array with the fields (columns) from m2. I know how to fill an array with the rows from m1, and from there I would be able to figure out the 'dot product'.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: While it would be fairly easy to implement dot product in `awk` the error checking alignment checking will make this not a trivial throw away kinda program. Have you thought of using a language that has matrix support like Python, Ruby, Perl?

Comment: @Jake, have you seen the common awk idiom `awk 'NR == FNR {print "line from file1"; next} {print "line from file2"}' file1 file2` ?? If not, read some [tag:awk] questions and answers

Comment: Even if you don't know how to do it using any specific tool, at least show us the pseudo-code you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without any validation of the input files for the sizes.

it will be easier to break into two scripts, one for transposing the second matrix and one to create a dot product of vectors.  Also to simply `awk` code, you can resort to `join`.

```
$ awk '{m=NF/2; for(i=1;i<=m;i++) sum[NR] += $i*$(i+m)} 
   END {for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) 
          printf "%s", sum[i] (i==sqrt(NR)?ORS:OFS); 
        print ""}' <(join -j99 m1 <(transpose m2))
```

where `transpose` function is defined as

```
$ function transpose() { awk '{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) a[NR,j]=$j}
                          END {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                 for(j=1;j<=NR;j++) 
                                   printf "%s",a[j,i] (j==NR?ORS:OFS)}' "$1"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with GNU Octave:

```
octave --eval 'load("m1"); load("m2"); m1*m2'
```

Output:

```
ans =                              

    50    60
   114   140
```

However, assuming well-formatted files you can do it like this with GNU awk:

*matrix-mult.awk*

```awk
ARGIND == 1 {
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    m1[FNR][i] = $i
  m1_width  = NF
  m1_height = FNR
}

ARGIND == 2 {
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    m2[FNR][i] = $i
  m2_width  = NF
  m2_height = FNR
}

END {
  if(m1_width != m2_height) {
    print "Matrices are incompatible, unable to multiply!"
    exit 1
  }
  for(i=1; i<=m1_height; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=m2_width; j++) {
      for(k=1; k<=m1_width; k++)
        sum += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j]
      printf sum OFS; sum=0
    }
    printf ORS
  }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f matrix-mult.awk m1 m2
```

Output:

```
50 60 
114 140
```

Answer (score 0):

If you process the second matrix before the first matrix, then you don't have to transpose the second matrix or to store both matrices in an array:

`awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR,i]=$i;w=NF;next}{for(i=1;i<=w;i++){s=0;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)s+=$j*a[j,i];printf"%s"(i==w?RS:FS),s}}' m2 m1`

When I replaced multidimensional arrays with arrays of arrays by replacing `a[NR,i]` with `a[NR][i]` and `a[j,i]` with `a[j][i]`, it made the code about twice as fast in `gawk`. But arrays of arrays are not supported by `nawk`, which is `/usr/bin/awk` on macOS.

Or another option is to use R:

`Rscript -e 'as.matrix(read.table("m1"))%*%as.matrix(read.table("m2"))'`

Or this gets the names of the input files as command line arguments and prints the result without column names or row names:

`` Rscript -e 'write.table(Reduce(`%*%`,lapply(commandArgs(T),function(x)as.matrix(read.table(x)))),col.names=F,row.names=F)' m1 m2 ``